# Double integral over joint density function yields strange results

Tags: probability

I am very confused about this problem in a textbook. The premise is that there is a tank of fuel with a random amount $Y$ of fuel in it on a given day, from which a random amount $X$ is sold. The tank is not refilled during the day so $x \le y$. Then it says "assume that the joint density of these variables is" this function:

$$\displaystyle f(x, y) = 
\begin{cases}
2, & 0 < x \le y < 1\\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

I'm supposed to determine if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but this doesn't even appear to be a valid probability density function to me. The marginal distributions of $x$ and $y$ don't seem to be valid.

$$h(x) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} 2\,dy = \int\limits_{0}^{1} 2\,dy = 2 \neq 1$$

Likewise for the marginal distribution $g(y)$, and obviously the double integral over $x$ and $y$ gives the same thing: $2$.

Am I approaching this completely wrong? Is there a typo in my textbook?

Comment: The double integral of $f$ over the entire $xy$-plane is $1$, not $2$. Note that the integral bounds on $x$ (as the inner variable) are $0$ to $y$.

Comment: The identity $g(x)=2y$ seems slightly absurd, no?

Comment: It does, @Did. I have never studied multivariable calculus qua itself, so this has me a bit confused. Your answer was quite helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once again the confusion disappears if one takes care to write down the densities as usual functions, **using indicator functions** if need be.

Here the joint density $f$ is a function defined **on the whole plane $\mathbb R^2$** by
$$
f(x,y)=2\,\mathbf 1_{0\lt x\lt y\lt1},
$$
hence one can check that
$$
\iint_{\mathbb R^2}f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=\int_0^1\int_0^y2\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=\int_0^12y\,\mathrm dy=1.
$$
Likewise, the marginal densities $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are functions defined **on the whole line $\mathbb R$** by
$$
f_X(x)=\int_\mathbb Rf(x,y)\,\mathrm dy=\mathbf 1_{0\lt x\lt 1}\int_x^12\,\mathrm dy=2(1-x)\,\mathbf 1_{0\lt x\lt1},
$$
and
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_\mathbb Rf(x,y)\,\mathrm dx=\mathbf 1_{0\lt y\lt 1}\int_0^y2\,\mathrm dy=2y\,\mathbf 1_{0\lt y\lt1}.
$$